# Install PHP5.3 with apache on ubuntu14.04

Tags: php, apache

I need to install php5.3 for my cake php project.
I installed php5.3.29 and apache separately.
now in terminal it shows the php version as 5.3.29
and while i run localhost/info.php it shows the following output on browser

```
<?php 

phpinfo();

?>
```

Tried many solutions here but none worked

How can i solve this?

Comment: You haven't set the handler for `*php` files to PHP.

Comment: @Phylogenesis how can i set that. Can u guide me

Comment: It's as good as a text file to apache right now

Comment: That entirely depends on your operating system. Most Linux distributions normally handle this sort of thing in packages. One other thing, is there a reason you're installing 5.3? That version is woefully out of date and [will no longer receive updates](http://php.net/eol.php).

Comment: yeah i know that but still the project is alredy on 5.3 so for the time being i need to install 5.3(my bad luck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
o perl -pe 's|\Q.ph(p[345]?\E|.ph((p[345]?)| if $. <= 3'  /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf
```

This made it work.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get remove apache* php*`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apache2 php5`

if need mysql & phpmyadmin
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server phpmyadmin`

Comment: I have tried this. This installs php 5.5 so doesn't help me.